# Repsonsive Webpage

Tags: html, css, dom

I've been designing a webpage which I'm hoping will turn into a site which I'll be using in the future.

I've got a situation with my CSS, if the user increases the zoom level on his browser the webpage will become distorted. I'm not a very good Web designer at this stage and I'm still learning in the areas which I lack in.

Could some of you geniuses point me into the right direction on how my CSS can be improved. Below is my source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Shop1</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header-content">
    <div id="header-brand">
      <Label id="header-content-heading">Meta-eShop</Label>
    </div>
    <div id="header-links">
      <input type="text" id="search-product-text" placeholder="Search.." />
      <a href="#" title="Login/Register" id="header-login">Login/Register</a><a id="header-cart" href="#" title="basket">Basket</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="side-nav-bar">

  </div>
  <div id="main-body-container">
    <div id="main-body-section">
      <div id="main-body-content">
        <p id="intro">Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa, sollicitudin a feugiat vel, feugiat in enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
          posuere cubilia Curae; Duis non ligula magna. Proin commodo, felis ac viverra condimentum, tortor metus aliquet lacus, sed maximus lacus urna scelerisque urna. Nulla condimentum enim ac viverra fermentum. Vestibulum accumsan velit molestie arcu
          tincidunt, porttitor volutpat leo ornare. Duis faucibus justo quis est congue ultrices. Nam metus nulla, accumsan in vulputate ut, viverra eget lorem.</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa, sollicitudin a feugiat vel, feugiat in enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ante.
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa, sollicitudin a feugiat vel.
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa, sollicitudin a feugiat vel, feugiat in enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ante.
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa, sollicitudin a feugiat vel.
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa.
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa.
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa.
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <img src="../img/200x200.png"><br> Quisque sed risus consequat, mattis libero in, hendrerit ligula. Nam ut hendrerit augue. Phasellus justo massa.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
html{
height:100%;
width:auto;
font-family:"arial","helvetica",sans-serif;
} 
body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
} 
:root{ 
--bg-color: rgba(246,246,246,.8); 
--bg-color-side: rgba(246,246,246,1); 
--font-upper: "Brush Script Std", "Brush Script MT","Cursive";
--font-color: rgba(100,100,100,1.0);
--hover: 2px 2px 5px grey; 
} /*header content*/ 
#header-content{
width:100%;
height: 15%;
background-color: var(--bg-color);
display:inline-block;
border-bottom: var(--font-color) solid 3px;
position:fixed;
} 
#header-brand{
float:left;
margin:20px;
margin-left: 150px; 
font-size:3em;
border:var(--font-color) dashed 2px;
padding:5px;
font-family: var(--font-upper);
border-radius:5px;
} 
#header-links{
float:right;
margin-right:5%;
margin-top: 45px;
} 
#header-links #search-product-text{
margin-right:5px;
padding-left:10px;
margin-right:50px;
font-size:1em;
border-radius:10px;
} 
#header-links #header-login, #header-links #header-cart{
font-size: 1em;
padding-right:20px;
text-decoration: none;
} 
#header-links #header-login, #header-links #header-cart, #header-links #search-product-text, #header-links #search-product-submit{
color:var(--font-color);
} 
#header-login{
border-radius: 10px;
} 
#header-login:hover{
text-shadow: var(--hover);
} 
#header-cart:hover{
text-shadow: var(--hover);
} 
/*main container content*/ 
#side-nav-bar{
float:left;
width:10%;
height: 100%;
background-color:var(--bg-color-side);
overflow:visible;
position: absolute;
margin-top:7.55%;
position:fixed;
border-right: solid var(--font-color) 3px;
} 
#main-body-container{
height:80%;
padding-top: 8%;
} 
#main-body-section{
width:65%;
height: 99%;
margin-left:20%;
}
#main-body-content{
width:100%; 
height:100%;
} 
/*----------------------------------------------------*/ 
/*row style*/ 
.row {
height:auto;
width:100%;
display:flex;
align-content: center;
} 
.col-3{
width: 32.3%;
padding:1%;
height:auto;
float:left;
} 
.col-3 img{
width: auto;
margin-left: 20%;
}
.col-4{
width:25%;
padding:1%;
height:auto;
float:left;
} 
.col-4 img{
width: auto;
margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Reckon you could un-minify your css so it's readable?

Comment: Add <html lang="en"> inside the top of the html. You should always use a language code. Also add desription word to the alt tag of the images

Comment: Andy Holmes, CSS layout has been corrected to make it readable

Answer (score 1):

First step: You should make your images responsive so that they don’t break the columns on small screens. In the CSS file, add:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

But there are some more issues. The columns get too narrow on small screens. Four columns on wide screens should turn to only tow columns or even one on small mobile displays. Unfortunately, I am not used with the flexbox model yet. In a layout without flexbox you could use media queries in your CSS like these:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------*/ 
/*row style*/ 

.row {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
} 
.col-3 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
} 
.col-4 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
} 
.col-3 p.image,
.col-4 p.image {
    text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .col-3 {
        width: 32.3%;
        padding: 1%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
    } 
    .col-4 {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 1%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
    } 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .col-3 {
        width: 32.3%;
        padding: 1%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
    } 
    .col-4 {
        width: 25%;
        padding: 1%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
    } 
}
```

This does not work with your code, but you might find a solution. Anyway, very old browsers do not support flexbox ([see caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)), and at least for Internet Explorer 9, which is still in use by people with Windows XP, you should build a workaround.

The last issue is, that the content is not fully visible on small screen sizes, because it slips under the heading section. I don’t have a solution at the moment. I should have to learn the flexbox stuff by myself at first (which I haven’t found the time yet).

Nevertheless, I hope I could help at least a bit. Maybe some of the geniuses here can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

While you're learning, you could maybe take a look at Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/)

Bootstrap is a Web framework that's responsive by default - you use its tags in HTML and it makes it responsive when you re-size pages etc. Some people might not like to use Bootstrap because it does a lot of the hard work for you, so if you're one of these people, you can check out how to do it in JavaScript (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp).

Comment: I admit I've had a quick look at bootstrap, but as a learner I find it overwhelming. But thank you for your input may have another look into it